# NPM: module installation for a command line node tool?

Tags: node.js, command-line, npm

I have a command line tool written in node. I'd like to:

- Have the app be able to load its dependencies and work. Currently, after `npm install -g <somemodule>` that module is still not available. Things didn't used to work this way.
- Not have to run `npm link` on every folder, as I have read in the [NPM 1.0 docs](http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/03/23/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/). The above docs also talks about $PATH, which seems unrelated to the topic as I care about node modules, not binaries.

**How can/should a node command line tool handle its dependencies** so that the command line tool can run from any directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add following in the main file of your node.js app, assuming your file name is `node-binary.js`.

```
#! /usr/bin/env node

// your app code
console.log('TEST node binary');
```

And, in package.json file you need to specify which is the entry point of your app

```
...
"preferGlobal": "true",
"bin": {
    "node-binary": "node-binary.js"
},
...
```

and run the command `npm link` in the app directory. You should now be able to use `node-binary` command from any directory.

Hope that helps... :)

Comment: Another thing that I interpreted from your question is you want to run the module from any directory, irrespective of where its dependencies are installed. it is correct?

Comment: how do i install my module globally from my local repo so I can test it works?

Comment: You could `npm pack` and then do an `npm i -g pack.tgz`.